# Javascript Timer with Array Query

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a website which takes an input date time (Generated from c# endpoint) for a location in the world (e.g. singapore / london) and then displays the current time from that location and starts "ticking"

When the clock ticks (and loads) I need it to search through a datetime array with start and end dates in it which define 30 minute timeslots throughout a day.

With these two pieces of information i need to then get the array index of the item which the current time sits within (the array is shown below)

```
function (timeslotDate) {
    var current = timeslotDate.toDate();
    global_timeslots = new Array();
    global_timeslots['0'] = new Array(2, current.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(0, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['1'] = new Array(3, current.setHours(0, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(0, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['2'] = new Array(4, current.setHours(1, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(1, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['3'] = new Array(5, current.setHours(1, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(1, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['4'] = new Array(6, current.setHours(2, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(2, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['5'] = new Array(7, current.setHours(2, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(2, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['6'] = new Array(8, current.setHours(3, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(3, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['7'] = new Array(9, current.setHours(3, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(3, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['8'] = new Array(10, current.setHours(4, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(4, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['9'] = new Array(11, current.setHours(4, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(4, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['10'] = new Array(12, current.setHours(5, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(5, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['11'] = new Array(13, current.setHours(5, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(5, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['12'] = new Array(14, current.setHours(6, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(6, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['13'] = new Array(15, current.setHours(6, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(6, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['14'] = new Array(16, current.setHours(7, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(7, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['15'] = new Array(17, current.setHours(7, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(7, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['16'] = new Array(18, current.setHours(8, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(8, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['17'] = new Array(19, current.setHours(8, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(8, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['18'] = new Array(20, current.setHours(9, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(9, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['19'] = new Array(21, current.setHours(9, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(9, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['20'] = new Array(22, current.setHours(10, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(10, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['21'] = new Array(23, current.setHours(10, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(10, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['22'] = new Array(24, current.setHours(11, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(11, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['23'] = new Array(25, current.setHours(11, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(11, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['24'] = new Array(26, current.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(12, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['25'] = new Array(27, current.setHours(12, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(12, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['26'] = new Array(28, current.setHours(13, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(13, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['27'] = new Array(29, current.setHours(13, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(13, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['28'] = new Array(30, current.setHours(14, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(14, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['29'] = new Array(31, current.setHours(14, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(14, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['30'] = new Array(32, current.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(15, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['31'] = new Array(33, current.setHours(15, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(15, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['32'] = new Array(34, current.setHours(16, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(16, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['33'] = new Array(35, current.setHours(16, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(16, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['34'] = new Array(36, current.setHours(17, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(17, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['35'] = new Array(37, current.setHours(17, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(17, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['36'] = new Array(38, current.setHours(18, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(18, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['37'] = new Array(39, current.setHours(18, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(18, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['38'] = new Array(40, current.setHours(19, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(19, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['39'] = new Array(41, current.setHours(19, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(19, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['40'] = new Array(42, current.setHours(20, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(20, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['41'] = new Array(43, current.setHours(20, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(20, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['42'] = new Array(44, current.setHours(21, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(21, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['43'] = new Array(45, current.setHours(21, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(21, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['44'] = new Array(46, current.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(22, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['45'] = new Array(47, current.setHours(22, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(22, 59, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['46'] = new Array(48, current.setHours(23, 0, 0, 0), current.setHours(23, 29, 59, 0));
    global_timeslots['47'] = new Array(49, current.setHours(23, 30, 0, 0), current.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0));
}
```

So if the current time is 3:45am then the timeslot index returned should be 7.  The reason for this functionality is that every time it goes into a new timeslot it will update something on the screen (through an endpoint of some kind).  I am pulling my hair out however getting a date object from c# (as a string), starting a ticking clock then checking the array above.  Some rough guidance would be appriciated..

An example input string (generated from my c# endpoint) is : `'09-16-2015 03:24:36'`

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js will probably be your best friend for this project. http://momentjs.com/docs/

It does all sorts of date magic, including handling the conversion of strings in many different formats to datetime values.

Comment: So..i have tried using moment.js to parse my string etc. but getting it to get a date object from my string, then firstly start a ticking clock, then after that check the object above and get the timeslot.  It also needs to take into consideration that it may run over days so when the day changes it needs to cater for that too...i was also having some major issues with global variables..aarrgghhh...